# Do we need canonical question for "trying to overwrite file which is also in package"?

Tags: discussion

I found a lot of duplicates by [this query](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=trying%20to%20overwrite%20which%20is%20also%20in%20package). There are many possible solutions shown but they are mostly incomplete and do not show the right way which will work in all situations.
I think we need one best with explanation or at least to clean up there.

Comment: There is one already, the one that has "file" in the title.

Comment: Preferably this one http://askubuntu.com/q/389549/169736

Comment: I think this one is more general: http://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in

Comment: That's the worse answer that can be given. Is not that is wrong, because it solve the problem, but solve the problem the wrong way and also is likely to break something else.